# Installing Ubuntu Server 22.04 in Hyper-V: Network Connection; Continue without network

Tags: networking, server, configuration, hyper-v

I have installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 from bootable USB directly onto Hyper-V Server 2019 which lays on an old computer of mine.

Problem: when installing, I come to Network configs and only option there is "Continue without network".

sudo apt-get update doesn´t work.
Here I become failed to fetch to ubuntu archives.

What I did:

- Secure Boot disabled
- On Hyper-V I can come to Google
- rebooted the Ubuntu mashine
- checked Network Adapter, it´s same adapter which I use on other VMs
- created Internal Adapter and connected it to the External
- network settings reseted
- completly reinstalled Hyper-V server
- created internal adapter, connected it to external
- attached only internal adapter to Ubuntu
- countinue without network disapears when installing, instead there said "done"
- failed unmounting /cdrom in Hyper-V after reboot

Any suggestions would be appreciated
tnx

Answer (score 0):

@countinue without network
dont forget to create Internal Adapter and connect it to the External
before installing any VMs on Hyper-V

@failed unmounting /cdrom in Hyper-V after reboot
turn off the mashine
in BIOS settings from VM -> Boot from IDE (which is actually a VHD where Linux has been installed)

Done

- apt-get update
  works now

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you put in an improper subnet for your IP and you aren't using DHCP.

[Sample Screen With Proper Subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ1t1.png)

When you put in proper settings for your network, it will change to "Done"